# php formatting numbers?

Tags: php, numbers, number-formatting

I would like to format numbers, so numbers woul format like this:

```
1=1
10=10
100=100
1000=1,000
10000=10,000
100000=100,000
1000000=1,000,000
```

I think it can be done with number_format(), but right now I`m having a problem, so if the number is 35679 it shows 35,679,000.

Comment: $english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', ','); will result 35,679.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want 35679 to show up as 35,679:

```
number_format(35679,0,'',',');
```

First parameter is the input number.
 Second is the amount of decimals.
 Third is the decimal separator (not needed without decimals).
Last is the thousands separator.

(You probably set the number of decimals to 3)

Answer (score 0):

Please see [THIS](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) for a complete explanation of number_format().
For example you would need `number_format($number, 0)` if the default settings are present or `number_format($number, 0, '.', ',')` for comma to be used as thousand seperator.